# AsyncTasks in different custom compound views don't start simultaneity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-custom-view

I have created a custom compound view that contains some `TextView` and a `ProgressBar`. After adding these components I start an animation for complete view entrance. Also I have defined an `AnimationListener` that when the animation is completed, it starts an `AsyncTask` that will be used to animate `ProgressBar`. Here is what I done. After adding inner components I have this animation:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    mAnimationId);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    new ProgressTak().execute();
                }
            });
            startAnimation(animation);
```

And here is `AsyncTask`:

```
class ProgressTak extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mProgress; i++) {
                i++;
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

    }
```

Everything works fine. But the problem is when I add two instance of my custom view to an activity, the progress bar animation in second activity starts when the progress bar animation in first activity is completed. But I want they act concurrently. What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [android developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

So you should do something like

```
new ProgressTak().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Hope this helps